# Right align fontawesome icon on li

Tags: html, css

I have the following markup:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a> <i class="fa fa fa-chevron-right"></i></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2 is longer</a> <i class="fa fa fa-chevron-right"></i></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a> <i class="fa fa fa-chevron-right"></i></li>
</ul>
```

It appears like this ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hns0rp6p/)):

[image]

What I'm trying to do is "line up" the icons so they appear on the right, regardless of the length of the links in the `<a>` tag. I've mocked this up in Fireworks but it shows the idea of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

How is this possible? I am also using Bootstrap 3.3.7 but not sure if any utilities or classes in there would help.

I've tried putting a width on the `<a>` elements, but obviously that's quite restrictive and doesn't work well responsively.

Comment: Simple, use the `pull-right` class from Bootstrap on the ´<i>´ tag like this `<i class='fa fa-code pull-right'></i>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A flexbox approach:

```css
ul {
  width: 10em;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <ul class="fa-ul">
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a> <i class="fa fa fa-chevron-right"></i></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2 is longer</a> <i class="fa fa fa-chevron-right"></i></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a> <i class="fa fa fa-chevron-right"></i></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: What an elegant solution! No need to mess with `float: right` and then height and vertical alignment issues.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use float

```
li i {
  float : right; 
}
```

or you can use bootstrap class push-right like this

```
<li>
    <a href="#">Link 2 is longer</a> 
    <i class="fa fa fa-chevron-right push-right"></i>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check my snippet:

```css
ul {
  width: 200px;
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a> <i class="fa fa fa-chevron-right float-right"></i></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2 is longer</a> <i class="fa fa fa-chevron-right float-right"></i></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a> <i class="fa fa fa-chevron-right float-right"></i></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: A float works, but the floated element doesn't flow in the CSS order, so it won't stretch the height of the div, nor will you get vertical alignment quite right either.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this CSS - a combination of relative position with fixed with for `li` and absolute position, right aligned, fo the `i` tags:

```
li { 
width: 130px; 
  position: relative;
}
li i {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 1px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z9hcub4w/1/

Answer (score 0):

What about giving li's a width with float right on the i elements.

```
  i {
        float: right;
    }


 li {
    width: 12em;

   }
```